# PHP MySQL Success Message Always Shows

Tags: php, mysql, message

I'm having an issue with a success message or fail message. My code is below, but the issue is that no matter what, the success message always shows - even before the query occurs. If I remove the success message `if` command, then it doesn't do what it's supposed to do.

```
 isset($_POST['delete']);
 $systemid = $_POST['systemid'];
 $clientiddel = $_POST['clientiddel'];
 $querydel = "DELETE FROM ... WHERE customer = '" . $clientiddel . " ' AND system_id = '" . $systemid . "'";

  if(mysql_query($querydel))
{
    echo 'SUCCESS';
}
else
{
    echo 'FAILED' .mysql_error();
}
```

My form is

```
<form method='post' action='" . $_PHP_SELF . "'>
<input name='systemid' type='hidden' id='systemid' value='" . $row['system_id'] . "'><input name='clientiddel' type='hidden' id='clientiddel' value='" . $row['customer'] . "'><input name='delete' type='image' src='images/delete.gif' id='delete' alt='Delete' onclick='return confirm_delete()'>
</form>
```

The onclick function is

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function confirm_delete() {
  return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete \'".$row['system_id']."\' from this account? ');
}
</script>
```

EDIT:

Problem solved - adding an extra hidden field to the form named 'delete' makes it work the way it should. Also, this is the final source for this operation:

```
    if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
        $systemid = $_POST['systemid'];
        $clientiddel = $_POST['clientiddel'];
        $querydel = "DELETE FROM .... WHERE system_customer = '".$clientiddel." ' AND system_id = '".$systemid."'";

        if(mysql_query($querydel))
        {
            echo 'SUCCESS';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'FAILED' .mysql_error();
        }

}
```

Comment: using isset($_POST['delete']); in that context has no point.

Comment: Right, so as whirlwind said, you are running the code no matter what, even if $_POST['delete'] is not set. so change that to `if(isset($_POST['delete']){ ... that whole chunk of code here ...}` - and then brush up on mysqli or PDO and use prepared statements. mysql_ is deprecated and yo uare open to attacks.

Comment: Thanks guys. Even when I change the isset code it still doesn't work. If I remove it totally, the code works, but still displays the success message when the page is loaded just like originally.

Comment: and speaking on mysqli or PDO - I can't do it. I'm using an application that has everything hard coded in already and encrypted.

Comment: What is `confirm_delete()` ?

Comment: Had to leave the house so I don't have access to the source at the moment. The onclick function is a Javascript confirmation popup that works properly. I'll post it once I'm home again.

Comment: @user3247565 Ah that's alright, I thought it might've been an ajax request or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
     if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
        $systemid = $_POST['systemid'];
        $clientiddel = $_POST['clientiddel'];
        $querydel = "DELETE FROM ... WHERE customer = '" . $clientid . " ' AND system_id = '" . $systemid . "'";

        if(mysql_query($querydel))
        {
            echo 'SUCCESS';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'FAILED' .mysql_error();
        }
    ?>
```

Try like this and let me know if it works. If doesn't work enable your error_reporting(). Put these two lines at the beginning of the page

`ini_set('display_errors',1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);`

EDIT:

Change `$_PHP_SELF to $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" >
```

Comment: changing the first line to `isset($_POST['delete']){` causes a syntax error with an unexpected '{'. I did edit the action line.

Comment: Here is what I currently have `if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
        $systemid = $_POST['systemid'];
        $clientiddel = $_POST['clientiddel'];
        $querydel = "DELETE FROM ... WHERE system_customer = '".$clientiddel." ' AND system_id = '".$systemid."'";

        if(mysql_query($querydel))
        {
            echo 'SUCCESS';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'FAILED' .mysql_error();
        }
  }` It loads without error, but when I click my delete button it does not run the DELETE command. If I remove the whole isset line it will run but success is there on page load

Comment: What I can think of is that $_POST['delete'] isn't set. As @Darren pointed, you should update your question with confirm_delete() function.

Comment: Or you can add another hidden field like this : <input type="hidden" name="action" value="Submit"> and check if the form is submitted with : if($_POST['action'] == "Submit"){
 /* do something */
}

Comment: Ok, there is no ajax calls in that function. Well, you can try to set another hidden field, like I suggested above in comments. Or just instead of checking a $_POST['delete] , to check for  !empty($_POST['clientiddel']) && !empty($_POST['systemid'])

Comment: Adding the extra hidden field did it! I gave it the name of 'delete' and just ran it with the code. Works great now! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with the form. The `$_PHP_SELF` does not exist. What you wanted to use was `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`. You're best off not trying to deal with that variable and leaving the action empty:

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

Your PHP will always run.... You need to do something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    // run the PHP here.
}
```

#### Note

The `mysql_*` library is deprecated and set for deletion in the future. Please look into using more reliable libraries like `PDO` or `MySQLi`. It's not hard at all. Here's a simple PDO example to achieve what you're trying.

```
/* Connect to an ODBC database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$sql = "DELETE FROM table WHERE customer = :client_id AND system_id = :system_id";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':client_id', $_POST['clientiddel'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':system_id', $_POST['systemid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

<sup>*[Read More about PHP PDO here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)*</sup>

---

You need to supply the code for `confirm_delete()` that is present in your `delete` buttons' `onClick` attribute.

Comment: speaking on mysqli or PDO - I can't do it. I'm using an application that has everything hard coded in already and encrypted. I'm writing a module for it.

@michael - I actually made small changes to variables to make the post here. I'll edit the main

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with your $clientid variable, you declared it as $clientiddel

Try this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $systemid = $_POST['systemid'];
    $clientid = $_POST['clientiddel'];
    $strSQL = "DELETE FROM ... WHERE customer = '" . $clientid . " ' AND system_id = '" . $systemid . "'";
    $queryDel = mysql_query($strSQL);
    if(!$queryDel){
        echo "FAILED:" . mysql_error();
    } else {
        echo "SUCCESS";
    }
}
?>
```

EDIT:
They're right, you also did an error within your form tag, use this:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
```